# How to organize and group test cases in XCUI test automation framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I am using `XCUI` test framework for automating my iOS App test cases. I have separate tests for all modules. I need to specifically select particular cases from each module to set up a high level sanity run where I can run those tests alone. Do we have something similar to **Selenium TestNG** groups?

```
@Test (groups = { "bonding", "strong_ties" })
```

something similar to this for iOS XCUI?

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange your tests using path-like strings.

As per [xcodebuild documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)

> The `-only-testing` and `-skip-testing` options, which are optional, allow you to run only a specific test and to skip a test, respectively. They take an argument , which specifies the test to be executed or excluded. test-identifier's format is as follows:
>
> ```
> TestTarget[/TestClass[/TestMethod]]
> ```
>
> `TestTarget`, which is required, is the name of the test bundle. `TestClass` and `TestMethod`, which are both optional, respectively represent the name of the class and the name of the method to be tested.

Example usage:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Foo.xcworkspace \
-scheme Bar\
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,OS=12.3'
'-only-testing:TestGroup/TestClass' test
```

Check out [How to Get Started with XCUITest (iOS)](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/getting_started_xcuitest/) for initial instructions.

You might also find [EarlGrey framework](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey) useful

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Xcode (coming next week) adds new feature called Test Plans. It is designed for an enhanced test planning. 
It has no documentation, though you can watch a keynote and get more details about it.

---

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413/?time=1411